# How to stick text with a folder in Windows

Tags: windows, sticky-notes

Sometimes I feel that I **need to keep some notes about a folder**. And its really inconvenient to  keep that in a text file. And each time I need that information I have to open it and see it. But how it would be **if I could stick the text with the folder** so that I can see it right away when im inside the folder? I've attached a picture to make my point more clear.

Do you know any such software? or any trick that does this for me?

[image: Need something like this]

**EDIT:**
Thanks to *@Lamb* and *@JonathanReno* both for nice answers. If I define the requirement by a sequence of activities, it will be like

- I will come inside a folder.
- I will *Right Click > Click on Menu* or *Click any Button* so that I can get a text box to edit.
- After writing I will save it.
- The text will be visible right away. Even anytime later I came in this folder, it will be remain visible.

So given this situation, I think @Lamb's approach is closer. Its just one step away to show me the text since i ve to select the file (`readme`) ;) And its not that big deal for the time being I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible solution, **without any third party software**, is using the ***file preview*** feature of windows.

Enable Preview by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and place a text file in your folder describing the content *(name it so that it is arranged at the top inside the folder)*.
Anytime in future, when you browse to that folder, you will be able to see the notes you have kept in text file, in the preview pane. (of-course, without opening it)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screen shot preview pane]

I use this method quite often, its quick, no need of any plugin and no extra clicks required. You only need to open the text file when you have to edit it. This might not be the best solution but I think this is the most **Stable solution**.

Comment: Although the question stated they didn't want to use a text file, this is a good solution and is well explained.

Comment: thought that you were not preferring text file due to open and close burden.

Answer (score 3):

You can try FileNotes. You can download it from http://jmsoftware.webs.com/downloads.htm. With FileNotes installed, you can right-click any folder and then click **Notes**. If you want to look at the notes later, just right-click on the same folder and click **Notes** again.

Psst! Do tell me if this isn't what you want.